# Ограниченный доступ к веб-виджету

Tags: javascript, html, аутентификация, доступ, виджет

Всем привет. У меня есть сайт-сервис с большой базой данных по узкой тематике (скажем, астрономия). Заказчикам интересен мой контент, и они хотят, чтобы я предоставила им готовые блоки (виджеты) для вставки на их сайт. API для них сложно, им нужны именно готовые блоки с конкретной информацией.

У меня вопрос: можно ли отображать виджеты только на сайтах заказчиков и как это реализовать технически? Чтобы если какой-то умник скопировал код виджета к себе на посторонний сайт, то не смог увидеть содержимого.

Насколько я поняла HTTP_REFERER не подходит, т.к. его легко подделать. А какие есть варианты? Слышала про программные токены и возможность подписывать запросы, но не знаю, подходят ли они для моей задачи и как их практически реализовать. Посоветуйте плиз?

Если я начну сотрудничать с заказчиками, то внесу их в свою базу и смогу хранить там любую инфу, связанную с ними

Comment: Решение нашлось, задача выполнена и описана мною здесь: https://gist.github.com/mogilka/56a97958a6062dbb767e30261314e3d3